# unable to push docker images to ECR with Gitlab CI

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, amazon-ecr

I have set up the `gitlab-ci.yaml` to push the docker image to ECR. Below is the script file definition.

```
image: 
  name: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/cloud-deploy/aws-base:latest
  entrypoint: 
    - '/usr/bin/env'

stages:
  - build
  - deploy
services:
  - docker:dind

before_script:
  - >
    STS=($(aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity
    --role-arn arn:aws:iam::831955480324:role/gitlab-aws-access-role
    --role-session-name "GitLabRunner-${CI_PROJECT_ID}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"
    --web-identity-token $CI_JOB_JWT_V2
    --duration-seconds 3600
    --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]'
    --output text))
  - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${STS[0]}"
  - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${STS[1]}"
  - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="${STS[2]}"
  - TOKEN=$(base64 <<< $CI_JOB_JWT_V2)
  - echo $TOKEN
  - echo ${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}
  - aws sts get-caller-identity
  - aws s3 ls

Build:
  stage: build
  services:
  - docker:dind
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - >
      docker build
      --pull
      --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.title=$CI_PROJECT_TITLE"
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.url=$CI_PROJECT_URL"
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.created=$CI_JOB_STARTED_AT"
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.revision=$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.version=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
      --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
      .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
Deploy:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

The below script is working fine where I am not using aws image.

The following script is working fine where I am not using ECR.

```
image: docker:latest
stages:
  - build
  - deploy
services:
  - docker:dind
before_script:
  - echo -n $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER --password-stdin $CI_REGISTRY
Build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest || true
    - >
      docker build
      --pull
      --cache-from $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.title=$CI_PROJECT_TITLE"
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.url=$CI_PROJECT_URL"
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.created=$CI_JOB_STARTED_AT"
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.revision=$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
      --label "org.opencontainers.image.version=$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
      --tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
      .
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
Deploy:
  variables:
    GIT_STRATEGY: none
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - master
  script:
    - docker pull $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA
    - docker tag $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$CI_COMMIT_SHA $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
    - docker push $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:latest
```

The `aws s3` command is working fine but the docker commands are not working. I am getting the below error:
`Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?` 
I need to use both the docker and the aws images. One for building the docker image and the other for pushing the image to the ECR. What is the right approach and where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
before_script:
  - >
    STS=($(aws sts assume-role-with-web-identity
    --role-arn arn:aws:iam::831955480324:role/gitlab-aws-access-role
    --role-session-name "GitLabRunner-${CI_PROJECT_ID}-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}"
    --web-identity-token $CI_JOB_JWT_V2
    --duration-seconds 3600
    --query 'Credentials.[AccessKeyId,SecretAccessKey,SessionToken]'
    --output text))
  - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="${STS[0]}"
  - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="${STS[1]}"
  - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN="${STS[2]}"
  - TOKEN=$(base64 <<< $CI_JOB_JWT_V2)
  - echo $TOKEN
  - echo ${AWS_SESSION_TOKEN}
  - aws sts get-caller-identity
  - aws s3 ls
  - nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --storage-driver=overlay2 &
  - timeout 15 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 1; done"
```

Comment: The earlier scipt was working fine. I have updated the question with the working script.

Comment: @zilcuanu pls try with edit answer

Comment: I am getting the below error:
$ nohup /usr/local/bin/dockerd --host=unix:///var/run/docker.sock --host=tcp://127.0.0.1:2375 --storage-driver=overlay2 &
$ timeout 15 sh -c "until docker info; do echo .; sleep 1; done"
nohup: failed to run command '/usr/local/bin/dockerd': No such file or directory
errors pretty printing info
Client:
 Context:    default
 Debug Mode: false
Server:
ERROR: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?